# Iframe not full screen in apple browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am making a gaming website. I have just an iframe on my html page. This is it.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $game['iframe']; ?>" name="cloudgames-com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen id="game-iframe"></iframe>
```

It is full screen on mozilla and chrome but not on iphone and safari. A scroll appears. Can anyone help me out why it appears?